# Internal Server Error PHP

Tags: php, logging

I am getting an internal server error and after some exploration I think it is because I updated my PHP to version 5.6.17

I am having trouble finding the error log on my server. Have tried allocating a spot for it in php.in. These are the values I have changed.

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/phplog/php_errors.log
```

In my php file which is returning the 500 Internal Server Error I have:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/var/log/phplog/php_errors.log");
```

However, the error is not writing. Any help/guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this your private server or hosted somewhere?

Comment: It is hosted on godaddy @Sibidharan

Comment: give permission to your php error file. if you are using linux server. find error_log file in apche

Comment: @user1011332 godaddy servers wont allow access to /var folder. Try to set the path to your user space! It should work!

Answer (score 3):

comment all of this and add this line:

```
//error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
//ini_set('display_errors', 0);
//ini_set('log_errors', 1);
//ini_set("error_log", "/var/log/phplog/php_errors.log");

ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

and this [reference](http://www.kreci.net/web-development/how-to-enable-error-reporting-in-php-script/) if you want to read more